# Type is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refs

Tags: typescript, types, jestjs, enzyme, next.js

I am using NextJS with Typescript. I am trying to test my application using Jest+Enzyme. I am getting the following error message:

**
Test suite failed to run

```
TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
__tests__/Quest.spec.tsx:15:27 - error TS2605:
```

> JSX element type 'Quest' is not a constructor function for JSX
>   elements.
>         Type 'Quest' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refs

**

I have added the code for my Test file and the code for which I have written the test:

**Quest.spec.tsx** (Test file)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Quest from '../Quest';

describe('Quest page', () => {
  it('should render without throwing an error', function () {
    const wrapper = mount(<Quest/>);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by:  yarn upgrade @types/react@latest and I updated the import statements for both the test.tsx file and my main code file to import * as React from 'react';